# Ruby: combine two-dimensional arrays into a single array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

what is the cleanest way to turn these two arrays of arrays:

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

and

```
[[1, 'c'], [2, 'd']]
```

into a single array of hashes with arbitrary keys like this:

```
[{:id => 1, :foo => 'a', :bar => 'c'}, {:id => 2, :foo => 'b', :bar => 'd'}]
```

to elaborate, position 0 of every internal array should map to the :id key, position 1 of the internal arrays of the first array should map to the :foo key, and position 1 of the internal arrays of the second array should map to the :bar key. further, the :id key of each hash should not repeat, and each hash should have an :id, :foo, and :bar key.

Comment: They don't look arbitrary. The keys names are the same in the two hashes.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, preferable with a better example.

Comment: @sawa arbitrary meaning they are not part of the original data set, which is the two arrays of arrays, but not arbitrary in the sense of being meaningless.

Comment: @CarySwoveland i'll edit the question to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarify by [decomposing](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition)  the block variables:

```
a = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
b = [[1, 'c'], [2, 'd']]

a.zip(b).map { |(id,foo),(_,bar)| {id: id, foo: foo, bar: bar } }
  #=> [{:id=>1, :foo=>"a", :bar=>"c"}, {:id=>2, :foo=>"b", :bar=>"d"}]
```

Comment: Cool.. +1. Nice way to use `#zip` and `#map`/